# Angular bootstrap calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, angular-bootstrap

Here is a pretty clean and easy to use calendar made in Angularjs.

https://mattlewis.me/angular-bootstrap-calendar/

If you click on the number at the edge of any day, you'll be switched to the day view. **I want to disable that but I have no idea how to.**

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should add the

```
on-drill-down-click="false"
```

attribute to the calendar directive, together with the other options

```
<mwl-calendar
   .... 
   on-drill-down-click="false" >
</mwl-calendar>
```

https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar#documentation

Comment: Yup! That worked, thanks :D Can I has some rep, I need to start up voting or I'll go crazy

Answer (score 2):

as per the latest version, this has been changed to `on-view-change-click="false"`